# Better way for repetitive copy-paste sql-query with many similar LEFT JOINs

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a very repetitive query which queries each of the fixed size ratings.
Have someone a hint how I can improve this query? But I don't want to build this query textwise in a stored procedure...

Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT u.*,
r1.rating, r2.rating, r3.rating, r4.rating, r5.rating, r6.rating, r7.rating, r8.rating, r9.rating,
r10.rating, r11.rating, r12.rating, r13.rating, r14.rating, r15.rating, r16.rating, r17.rating, r18.rating, r19.rating
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN Rating r1 on u.id = r1.userId AND r1.recipeId = 1
LEFT JOIN Rating r2 on u.id = r2.userId AND r2.recipeId = 2
LEFT JOIN Rating r3 on u.id = r3.userId AND r3.recipeId = 3
LEFT JOIN Rating r4 on u.id = r4.userId AND r4.recipeId = 4
LEFT JOIN Rating r5 on u.id = r5.userId AND r5.recipeId = 5
LEFT JOIN Rating r6 on u.id = r6.userId AND r6.recipeId = 6
LEFT JOIN Rating r7 on u.id = r7.userId AND r7.recipeId = 7
LEFT JOIN Rating r8 on u.id = r8.userId AND r8.recipeId = 8
LEFT JOIN Rating r9 on u.id = r9.userId AND r9.recipeId = 9
LEFT JOIN Rating r10 on u.id = r10.userId AND r10.recipeId = 10
LEFT JOIN Rating r11 on u.id = r11.userId AND r11.recipeId = 11
LEFT JOIN Rating r12 on u.id = r12.userId AND r12.recipeId = 12
LEFT JOIN Rating r13 on u.id = r13.userId AND r13.recipeId = 13
LEFT JOIN Rating r14 on u.id = r14.userId AND r14.recipeId = 14
LEFT JOIN Rating r15 on u.id = r15.userId AND r15.recipeId = 15
LEFT JOIN Rating r16 on u.id = r16.userId AND r16.recipeId = 16
LEFT JOIN Rating r17 on u.id = r17.userId AND r17.recipeId = 17
LEFT JOIN Rating r18 on u.id = r18.userId AND r18.recipeId = 18
LEFT JOIN Rating r19 on u.id = r19.userId AND r19.recipeId = 19
```

edit:
Here are the table schemas

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    id  int     NOT NULL        PRIMARY KEY     AUTO_INCREMENT,
    [...]
);

CREATE TABLE Rating (
    id  int     NOT NULL        PRIMARY KEY     AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userId  int             NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (userId)            REFERENCES User(id),
    recipeId    int             NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (recipeId)          REFERENCES Recipe(id),
    rating      tinyint
);

ALTER TABLE Rating              ADD CONSTRAINT  UC_Rating_userId_recipeId   
    UNIQUE(userId, recipeId);
```

I want to show to each recipe's rating (there max. exactly 19) for every user.
The current query does exactly what it should, but I guess there will be a better way doeing that...

Comment: Please post the table schemas for your tables (user, rating, other relevant tables and attributes).
Please provide some example data.
And what your expected result is.
What are unique column combinations on your tables?

Comment: This feels like you're trying to pivot, because there's so many better ways to do this if you want typical relational output.  Maria doesn't pivot well, you're better off doing it in client code (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pivoting-in-mariadb/)

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at the pivot feature later, cause I want to use this query in a View later.

Answer (score 0):

**REMARK**
Because you have not declared your table schemas, I might **guess** wrong here.

**Option A**

MariaDB got Common Table Expressions in 10.2.1 [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/common-table-expressions-overview/).

I'm assuming `Rating` UNIQUE on (userId, recipeId).
You can try factoring out the join using CTE's.
In general, if you want more columns, you have to write a sub-select (in this case).

**Option B (scales by adding rows)**

Would more rows also be acceptable?
Something like

```
userId | recipeId | rating  
  1    |    1     |   r1   -- <--- value of r1 attached to recipeId 1
  1    |    2     |   r2   -- <--- value of r2 attached to recipeId 2
  1    |    3     |   r3   -- <--- value of r3 attached to recipeId 3
```

How about this?

```
SELECT userid,  
       recipe_id,  
       (SELECT rating  
        FROM userrr u  
        INNER JOIN rating r  
        ON u.userid = r.user_id AND r.recipe_id = crossed.recipe_id  
        WHERE u.userid = crossed.userid  
       ) AS rating_value  
FROM ( SELECT userid,  
              recipe_id  
       FROM userrr  
       --                      vvv--- extend it to 200 VALUES if you like.
       CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2)) AS recipes (recipe_id)  
     ) AS crossed (userid, recipe_id) ;
```

which gets you this juicy

```
 userid | recipe_id | rating_value 
--------+-----------+--------------
      1 |         1 | yummy
      1 |         2 | yawn
      2 |         1 | mhm
      2 |         2 | yuk
```

**EDIT A**
You can use [MariaDB Sequences](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/)
to generate a sequence of numbers like so:

```
SELECT * FROM seq_1_to_5;
```

You can use this instead of the `VALUES (1), (2)` code.

**EDIT B**

```
SELECT userid,  
       recipe_id,  
       (SELECT rating  
        FROM userrr u  
        INNER JOIN rating r  
        ON u.userid = r.user_id AND r.recipe_id = crossed.recipe_id  
        WHERE u.userid = crossed.userid  
       ) AS rating_value  
FROM ( SELECT userid,  
              seq  
       FROM userrr  
       --                      vvv--- extend it to 200 VALUES if you like.
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT seq FROM seq_1_to_5) AS recipes  
     ) AS crossed (userid, recipe_id) ;
```

Comment: This answer will produce an error:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES (1), (2)) AS recipes (recipe_id)        ) AS crossed (userid, recipe_id)' at line 13

It's an unexpected "VALUES" after "CROSS JOIN"

CTE is not supported by my rpovider at the moment because its version pre 10.2.1

Comment: @5im Then you can use `SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3` maybe?

Comment: @5im [MariaDB Sequences](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/) You can try `SELECT * FROM seq_1_to_5` in the second part of the `CROSS JOIN` to generate the numbers 1 to 5. Please compare to **EDIT A**. It's enabled by default since MariaDB 10.1, and available even earlier.

Comment: @flutter thx, SELECT * FROM seq_1_to_5 brings it a step further. Now its an syntax error in "AS recipes (recipe_id)" at the opening bracket it says:
"unexpected '(' , expecting UNION_SYM or ')' "

Comment: Did you try removing the parenthesis () and its content? Please remove `(recipe_id)` from that part. There will be another place to name this thing, namely `AS crossed (userid, recipe_id)`. What this does is just give the name `recipe_id` to the int from the sequence, such that it can be used in the `WHERE crossed.recipe_id` part. From the linked MariaDB documentatation, we can see that the field will be called `seq` always. So please try replacing the column name by `seq` or leave it out. If you don't name it `recipe_id`, then it's still `seq` and replace `crossed.recipe_id` with crossed.seq.

Comment: Or just directly use `seq`. See the manual for the column name (`seq`). I would help you, but I don't have mariaDB installed here :/ I wrote this by heart xD. There are just too many relational databases out there, to collect them all. They are just like these famous Pokemons.

Comment: Please read **EDIT B**. Does it work now? What's the DBMS saying now? I'll check back every few minutes, because we are both awake now.